# Controller did not get request

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui

I have JQuery function that takes dateStart and dateEnd from UI, and then pass these parameters to controller. The problem here is controller does not get any request and no error shown ? Could anyone explain why that happened?

JQuery:

```
$("#btn_search").click($.proxy(function () {

   var dateStart = document.getElementById('dataStart').value;
   var dateEnd = document.getElementById('dateEnd').value;

    KeyWord.getGroup(dateStart, dateEnd,
     function (data) {
       $("#view_table").ViewTable('option', 'data', data);
            },
            function () { },
            function () { Metronic.unblockUI(); });

        }))

var KeyWord = function () {
var url_Log = "api/Log/Search";
return {
    getGroup: function (dateStart, dateEnd, done, fail, always) {
        var jqxhr = $.get(url_Log, { dateStart: dateStart, dateEnd: dateEnd    });
        jqXhrHandler(jqxhr, done, fail, always);
    }
}
}();
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public string Search(DateTime? dateStart, DateTime? dateEnd)
    {
        LogDalc dalc = new LogDalc();

        DateTime _sdate = dateStart == null ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime)dateStart;
        DateTime _edate = dateEnd == null ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime)dateEnd;

        return dalc.Sel(_sdate, _edate);
    }
```

Comment: Have you used the developer tools in your browser to examine the request? (i.e. the "Net" tab in Chrome). Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your values for dateStart and dateEnd. What do they look like before you fire off your get? You're most likely going to want to use jQuery's .ToJSON() like so: `var dateStart = document.getElementById('dataStart').value.ToJSON();`

Comment: what I believe is dateStart and dateEnd do not pass to controller at all.

Comment: Do you have a route defined for this controller action? Default routes wont handle two parameters. You either add a route prefix or add it in the route table

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is how you are set the url, change

```
var url_Log = "api/Log/Search";
```

to

```
var url_Log = "/api/Log/Search";
```

Look, if you are in http://domain/Home/About and you execute the function, the url that is called is http://domain/Home/api/Log/Search, but, if you add the / at the beggnning of the url, ever the url that is called is http://domain/api/Log/Search